# libGDX : Set name for easier identification of any class

Tags: java, libgdx

In my game I created many `Array`'s libgdx class. I want to find specific array `findArray(String name)` with name like actors in following code:

```
public <T extends Actor> T findActor (String name) {
    Array<Actor> children = this.children;
    for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++)
        if (name.equals(children.get(i).getName())) return (T)children.get(i);
    for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++) {
        Actor child = children.get(i);
        if (child instanceof Group) {
            Actor actor = ((Group)child).findActor(name);
            if (actor != null) return (T)actor;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

How can I do this ??

Comment: what is the problem with the code now? But your code can be some how optimized.

Comment: Seems to me like you might want a Map of actors with the name as the key. In my game I tag a unique ID to an entity/actor in the level data however and the game can index them based on that - that also has the benefit of being able to have duplicate names without conflict. Simple integer comparisons are a lot cheaper than full string equality comparisons.

Comment: @Degen Sharew Thanx for your reply on my question.

Comment: @Gimby you'r alright. `HashMap` is perfect answer. THANX A LOT

Comment: Don't thank me, just promise you'll explore the basic JDK classes more so you know these extremely useful classes exist.

Comment: Ok, I will not thank you again :P hahaha